# PyQt: How do I figure out which encoding is used?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a py file using Qt Designer,i have a combobox and i read from a csv file.If the combobox choice is in the file,it prints something.

At the top of the script it says that: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

So, the error i get is this:

```
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'choice') is not in list
```

The 'choice' is of course in list.I believe its an encoding problem,but that's all i got.

u'choice' is a string and the list contains strings.

This is how i add items to the list:

```
import csv
list1=csv.reader(open('file.csv', "rb"))
list2=[]
for i in list1:
   list2.append(i)
```

Any ideas?Thanks.

Comment: And what value is PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'choice')? What is 'list' (presumably not the built-in type list)? What is the exact error message you got? What was the line of code you were executing?

Comment: paste a snippet where you add values to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has got nothing to do with encodings.

The error occurs simply because there are no strings in the list read from the csv file:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('tmp.csv', 'wb') as stream:
...     csv.writer(stream).writerow(['choice'])
... 
>>> lst = []
>>> with open('tmp.csv', 'rb') as stream:
...     for row in csv.reader(stream):
...         lst.append(row)
... 
>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import QString
>>> s = QString(u'choice')
>>> lst.index(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'choice') is not in list
>>> lst
[['choice']]
>>> lst[0].index(s)
0
```

The csv reader returns a *list of strings* for each row in the file.

Comment: The list2 is a list of strings ,not list of list of strings,if that's what you mean.So,you say that my list2 has no strings ? I am a little lost here.

Comment: In your code, `list1` is a `csv.reader`, which is a file-like object which parses csv files, row by row. In the `for` loop, `i` will be a list of strings representing the row. So `list2` becomes a list containing _lists_ of strings. Hence, there are no strings in `list2`, only lists (of strings). Of course, my reasoning is entirely based on the code you posted in your question - so if your _real_ code is different, my reasoning will be wrong.

Comment: It turns out its not encoding problem,I was using the wrong list.Thanks.